# How to add a moving progress spinner in Dialog Android

Tags: android, dialog

I want to put a spinner in a custom dialog in android, but it doesn't animate,anyone who knows why.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this,R.style.mydialog);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
dialog.show();
```

the dialog.xml is pasted below:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="@dimen/progressbar_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/progressbar_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/progressbar_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/progressbar_margin"
            android:indeterminateTint="@color/light_blue"
            android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_loading_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/progressbar_margin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/progressbar_message_text_size"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

the spinner doesn't animate at all:
[image: static spinner]

Comment: paste your style  `mydialog` also because it's working fine..

Comment: <style name="mydialog" parent="@android:Theme.Dialog">
       <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    </style>

Answer (score 1):

Try below Code this will help you :

```
if (dialog == null) {
        dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    }
    RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f);
    rotate.setDuration(2000);
    rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivProgress).setAnimation(rotate);
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: Thank you, but I just want to know why it doesn't animate in my code

Comment: Actuality it's does animated but because of android:indeterminateTint="@color/light_blue" and android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop" behavior is not visible.